# How to load a video file using remote url to AVPlayer in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, url, video, avplayer

I am trying to load a video file from remote location to AVPlayer. I can load video using the exact video url such as, https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.dea/big_buck_bunny.mp4. Its working when I tried this

```
URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.dea/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
```

But when the location is like http://192.162.0.25:1916/api/Video/1 , it s not loading the video in AVPlayer. I tried `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`, but didn't work. Please help ,

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: did you add `Allow Arbitrary Loads` in plist file under `App Transport Security Settings`? coz your video url is not https.

Comment: @ivarun thanks for the fast reply.  I have set it in lazy way.

Comment: so is it working fine for you?

Comment: @ivarun Like I z , it works when I tried using sample url with exact file name with extension. But not working when trying using the type of url "http://192.162.0.25:1916/api/Video/1" .

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to load this url  `http://192.162.0.25:1916/api/Video/1` which doesn't contain extension of file if that **1** is assumed as video and that was **.mp4** formate try to load along with extension like below

```
http://192.162.0.25:1916/api/Video/1.mp4
```

also don't forget to add below lines in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I have set the key in info.plist. Regarding the url, this is actually relative path . ie. when i try this url in pc browser it do play !!

Comment: No. issue remains, What i z is the url is not having the extension format as it is not the actual path .